# Is a query against an index containing all columns of a table as efficient as a query against the table itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-performance

I created a table in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordForm] (
    [WordFormId]   VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Ascii]        AS            (ascii([WordFormId])) PERSISTED,
    [WordId]       VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Primary]      BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [PosId]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [Definition]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sample1]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Synonym]      VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]  DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] DATETIME      NOT NULL,
    [Version]      ROWVERSION    NOT NULL,
    [Sample2]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sample3]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sample4]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sample5]      VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordFormId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordFormPos] FOREIGN KEY ([PosId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Pos] ([PosId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordFormWord] FOREIGN KEY ([WordId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Word] ([WordId])
);
```

I used the `WordFormId` as the primary key as it is unique and would be easy to look up.

Now on my front-end I realize there may be an advantage in me creating an identity key
and using that for a primary key for this table instead of WordFormId. Note that to put things in perspective this table will
hold a maximum of 9,000 rows. Data is inserted, added and updated very infrequently so I am not concerned about the time taken to update the index.

What I am thinking to do now is to:

a) Add an identity column as the primary key
b) Create an index of every column and order by WordId.

If I was to do these two things (a) and (b) would that be as efficient for queries? My thinking is 
that the query would use the index most of the time and this would be very similar to
before when I was using WordId as the primary key.

Comment: Currently you have clustered index by `WordFormID`. If all your queries use `WordFormID` as condition and return most of fields, then current solution is probably best. And, 9000 records is almost nothing anyway.

Comment: An index containing *all* columns of a table *is* the table itself, or rather just a copy of it. That's exactly what the clustered index is.

Comment: I forgot - if you want to use another field (`ID`) as primary key, don't make it clustered - keep clustered index as you have and everything will be OK :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Thanks. So if index update times are not an issue do you think the query will use that index.  If for example I do a query where WordFormId is > "A" and < "D" ?

Comment: @Arvo - I think you have a very good point. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @Arvo - I am looking into what you say.  Given the table definition.  How could I change the primary key to WordFormKey as an identity and leave the table clustered by WordFormId.   Can the table be clustered by something other than the primary key?

Comment: For changing primary key, search google or stackoverflow (I would do that using SQL management studio). Yes, you can create clustered index by any field(s) - do that before creating new primary key, otherwise it will be automatically bound with it.